# Terminating dataproc cluster with termination protection on instances produces red flag on cluster that never leaves; is cluster safe?

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-dataproc

I need to give a dataproc cluster protection like one can give an AWS EMR cluster. I saw that VM protection is a thing (but can't find anything about dataproc cluster protection), so I decided to try that out.

I made a dataproc cluster, for every instance of which I turned on deletion protection.

As a test of the safety of this arrangement, I tried to delete the cluster from the command line. As a result, the cluster now has a red flag on it all the time. The message reads:

> Invalid resource usage: 'Resource cannot be deleted if it's 
>   protected against deletion.'.

[image: Here's a picture.]

My question is this: given the persistent error message, is the cluster still ok? Have I accomplished the cluster protection that I sought? As far as I can tell, everything is still alright, I just wondered if anyone knows more about the state of the management of the cluster in the presence of this scary red exclamation mark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While your cluster is probably fine, it is now in error state and cannot be used for submitting jobs through the API, or updating.

Dataproc does not currently support delete protection. You can file a feature request here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187133&template=0

Comment: Can I, a non-google employee, use that link? It seems to me like an internal page. I don't, for instance, have an `@google.com` email address.

Comment: If you'd like to fix that, I may be amenable ;)